# How can I contain ".conda", ".continuum" etc files, when launching Jupyter and Anaconda?

Tags: file, anaconda, conda, jupyter

Whenever I launch Anaconda and any apps thourgh it, I get these ".blahblah" files randmoly spawned in my "User" folder. I tried changing the working directory of the whole Anaconda app but nothing changed regarding this issue. It is really distracting and ruins my file organization. Is there a fix for that? Thank you!

PS: It is the same type of files like the ".vscode" whenever launching VScode, but times x10.

Tried changing the wroking directory hoping it would fix it, but nothing.

Comment: Please realize that “dot” files and directories are hidden by default for most interfaces that do file listing. Writing these to user home is a standard convention for how to persist user-level state information. Consider instead adjusting your settings to hide these, and leave the files be.